# What is the maximum class number in the imaginary quadratic field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-d})$ for $d<10^6$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

[This site](http://www.numbertheory.org/php/classnonegtable_qfields.html) can calculate classes number of the imaginary quadratic field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-d})$ at $d<10^6$, from which I calculate $h\left(\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{-99986}\right)\right)=612$.And I calculated class number of $d\in[90000,99999]$ and found that there is no one larger than it. Then, since class number is on the rise in general, can it be explained that its class number is the largest at $d<10^6$? Or I want to know what the largest class number is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class number of $K=\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-152039})$ is $h_K=613$, and the class number of $K=\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-121469})$ is $h_K=614$, and so forth.

In fact, [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A081319) has a table giving the smallest squarefree integer $d$ such that $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-d})$ has class number $n$, for any given $n\le 4500$. According to this table, the largest class number is $h=2082$, such that $d=972221<10^6$, i.e., for  $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-972221})$.